# Automatically filling field in related content type

Tags: views, nodes

I have two similar content types on a Drupal 8 site: *groups* and *projects*. *Groups* can have child projects, but a project does not necessarily have a parent group. I have an entity-reference field on the *Project* content type, where a parent group can be added.

However, as I am setting up many different views, I would like these child projects to be added to the *Groups* nodes when users add parents to the *Project* nodes. In other words, I want to automatically update the field "Projects" on the related node of the "group" type.

How would I go about doing this? I see most people recommend showing a block on the node, but I would like to use this field in various views, so that won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using CER ( https://www.drupal.org/project/cer ) as suggested by Nikko worked as intended. When adding a parent group, the project is added to the group node. Which means I can hide the field, and will make setting up the different views on the page 100x simpler.

Answer (score 1):

So if I undersand you don't have any relation Groups -> Projects? You just have a relation Projects -> Groups (that you also call parents)? .
And you want to show by views, Groups and their children (projects)?

If this is what you want you have several choices.

- Add many relationships in the view advanced filters in order to reach groups projects, (could be tricky).
- Add a field entity relationship Groups -> project that you programmatically set on every projects insert/update/delete. Thanks to this it would be much more easier to build a view.
- create your own custom block, with your dedicated SQL query. listing all children of a group and attaching this block to all "groups" content type pages.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, they are only connected from projects to groups now.. The project type is set up like this:
http://imgur.com/a/uwSus

The reason I would like to add the fields to the nodes of the "parent" (to "relate" them back), is that I am setting up this and other views:
http://cc-moon.net/groups 
where I would like to show the child projects of each group in the table. However, if I try to link them in this view, I'm not able to show all groups because of that. I was thinking of trying Rules, but it looks like there is no Rules UI for D8 yet?

Comment: Indeed Rules seems out of activity... The best thing would be a 2 way reference field but nothing stable yet either... You can try https://www.drupal.org/project/cer but no promises about the result. 
I had to do something like that with "courses" and "lessons". Courses have lessons and a lesson is in a course. So i chosed to hook on node insert/update/delete to maintain these 2 relation fields programmatically.

Comment: I'm not proficient enough to do this programmatically, unfortunately. If Rules is a no-go, I will check out cer - thanks for the heads-up! Almost sad I chose D8 for this project instead of D7, even though D8 has it's benefits also.

Comment: CER is too recently ported as well, it seems. Does not show up in coffee or the menu, and when I googled the link referring to the admin-page it is non-existent. I guess I will leave it activated, and hope for an update in the future. :)

Comment: Nevermind - Rules was causing problems. Deleted this and flushed the cache, and it appeared. Will try it out, thanks! :)

EDIT - It worked!! Thanks a bunch! :)

Comment: Glad it helps!I'will probaly look closer to that CER module in the future :)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that create two references is a good option when you only need one in the project content type.

If you want create a view to show all the project of a group you should add in the view a Contextual Filter to the `field_related_research_group` field. If you want to show the view in a Group node page then you can chose the **Provide default value** option and as type **Content ID from URL**.

[image]

In your Filter Criteria the content type must be project.

Comment: This is not a good solution in this case. I am already using this approach to show information on nodes/user pages, but in this case I want the information to displayed to the user in searchable views of nodes of both content types - only one of them should be displayed at the time though. 

The module in question lets me achieve exactly that - the result can be seen at http://cc-moon.net/groups :)